# Plugging in Ehcache (second level caching) with lucene

Tags: lucene, ehcache, second-level-cache, ehcache-bigmemory

I want to cache the results returned by lucene search using some second level caching framework for faster cached responses. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

For frequently used queries (or subqueries), Lucene implements cached searches using [Filters](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_7_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/Filter.html), such as [FieldCacheTermsFilter](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_7_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/FieldCacheTermsFilter.html), or [CachingWrapperFilter](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_7_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/CachingWrapperFilter.html) to cache the results of an arbitrary filter type.